# Running PHP in Linux: how to fix "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library" issues?

Tags: php, php-extension

I have determined path to php but I'm getting the following php error in Ubuntu 22.04, I think I would need to load the Mysqlnd and mysqli for this issue

```
root@xxxx:~# php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.dll' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.dll (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.dll.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/php_pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fyu8.png)

I don't know what the exact steps is needed to follow. Kindly advise to load the Mysqlnd and mysqli

Comment: Normally you can install php modules via apt. Look at the list of packages and try to match them to the list which is in the error message.

Comment: Did you modify php.ini manually?

Comment: [PHP with pdo-mysql in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: fyi, `.dll`s are being used in Windows, Linux uses `.so`

Comment: @Olivier I didn't try to install php.ini manually

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've commented the following extenstion in this path /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini and issue got resolved.

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=pdo.so
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: No, you just disabeled  extensions, and also, you still don/t know how dll got in there, yes?

Comment: Yes, still I don't know How I got the dll in server but after disabling the extensions I didn't get the warning as before, so I thought it should be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you edited php ini the wrong way, or downloaded wrong PHP version as `dll` files are from windows, linux uses `so`
So smth like:

```
extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
```

is what you are searching for.
Download proper extensions (if missing), put them into the folder, add path
in php.ini. More details (from my php.ini):

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
;
; For example:
;
;   extension=mysqli
;
; When the extension library to load is not located in the default extension
; directory, You may specify an absolute path to the library file:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
;
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
;
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
```

Also, to get the proper location for php.ini, use `php --ini`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get, could you please provide the exact steps to follow.

Comment: run php --ini to get the location of php.ini file, than edit it and check for extensions. Replace .dll with appropriate .so files. Also, where did you downloaded php?

Comment: currently I'm using ubuntu server. 22.04 So I've added the following repository then installed the php 7,4 version.  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y